# Removing second single quote from a String in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to format an XML response in spring boot

In this response, I want to convert from
`TitleBrief='arg Nallin' 106 HD'` to 
`TitleBrief='arg Nallin 106 HD'`

I have to use Regex to be able to do this.  Kindly suggest a good regex.

I tried this but it is not working.

```
String test="='Narg Mallin' '";
String pattern1="(=')(.[^']*)'";
System.out.println(test.replaceAll("(=')","=\"");
```

Comment: Not sure if this works for all your cases, but it works for the case you present. `(?<!=)'(?!$)`

Comment: Is there a reason that you *have* to use regex? Also, is it possible that you could end up with a string with more than one single quote you need to remove? There's a method you could use to simplify the regex you write and take care of the second problem, but it adds some non-regex code.

Comment: I can also use nonregex method. How to do that?

Comment: I think regex is the way to go if your quotes can be anywhere inside your string.  I also tested the regex presented by @ctwheels and it seems golden. 

http://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyyd7ndar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, ctwheels's regex is a pretty easier way to solve this problem, and you can use it like this:

```
String test = "'arg Nallin' 106 HD'";
test.replaceAll("(?<!=)'(?!$)",""); // Returns "'arg Nallin 106 HD'"
```

---

However, in other programming languages that do not support lookbehinds (JavaScript, for example), this might be what you're looking for:

As an alternative, you can capture all the text instead, except for the quote you need to remove.

#### Code

---

```
String test = "'arg Nallin' 106 HD'";
test.replaceAll("^([^']*'[^']*)'(.*'.*)$","$1$2"); // Returns "'arg Nallin 106 HD'"
```

#### Explanation

---

```js
/^([^']*'[^']*)'(.*'.*)$/
```

- `([^']*'[^']*)` - This first capture group will:

  1. `[^']*` - Match everything but the single quote.
  2. `'` - Match the single quote you need to ignore.
  3. `[^']*` - Match everything but the single quote.
- `'` - Now, this quote is outside the other capturing groups, so it won't be present in `$1`, neither in `$2`
- `(.*'.*)` - Capture the rest of the content after the quote, and make sure there is at least one `'` left, so we can make sure the statement is an instance of a String.

Comment: Java doesn't support lookbehind ?